# Mutate IQueryable after calling ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo

Tags: c#, entity-framework, left-join, odata

I'm passing an OData query into a method, but I need perform an additional join to the query to retrieve some related data, as we want to get it all in one round trip to the DB.

```
        var products = query.ApplyTo(_repository.Query, ODataQuerySettings)
                         .Cast<Product>()
                         .ToList();

        // Ideally, this will be the only query that's run.
        var productImages = products.GroupJoin(_imageRepository.Query, p => p.ProductId, image => image.ProductId, (product, image) => new {
            Product = product,
            Image = image.DefaultIfEmpty()
        }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in productImages) {
            ...        
        }
```

This works, but is doing it with two queries. It seems that ApplyTo executes the query against the DB, rather than just providing you with a mutable IQueryable. If I remove the ToList() call from the first query, it throws an exception.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What kind of exception doest it throw ?

Comment: An InvalidOperationException: "This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code". I think it's to do with the DefaultIfEmpty method.

Comment: Actually, it's when calling GetEnumerator on the GroupJoin method.

Comment: Hmmm, it may be the `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Could you try to replace it by `Image = image ?? null` (while removing the ToList). Because I don't think Linq 2 entities likes DefaultIfEmpty on a complex object...

Comment: Nope, I tried removing DefaultIfEmpty, and still the same exception. Looking at the stack trace, it falls over when calling GetEnumerator.

Comment: and if you try to replace `Product = product, Image = image.DefaultIfEmpty()` by just `p = product.Id` ?

Comment: The same error. :( Thanks for trying to help, but I think we're going to try another approach instead.

Comment: @Tom, wondering what approach you took instead? Thank you! :)